# Applying text processing steps to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have text string and I am using following string functions to clean it. Now I want to scale it and apply it to dataframe. The challenge I am facing is that it is not applicable to dataframe. I tried applying on numpy array but result was null string.

Data frame is single column with similar string as given as line variable:

```
                               0
0   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US...
1   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/2...
2   Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like M...
3   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/201...
4   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT ...
```

``

```
 line = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; handyCafeCln/3.3.21)"
 re_print = re.compile('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
 remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
 remove_punc =str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
 line = line.translate(remove_digits)
 line = line.translate(remove_punc)
 line = line.split()
```

Result:

['Mozilla',
 'compatible',
 'MSIE',
 'Windows',
 'NT',
 'NET',
 'CLR',
 'handyCafeCln']

I tried packing same steps in a function but can't apply that on datframe with following error `Series' object has no attribute 'translate`

```
def clean_pairs(lines):
    re_print = re.compile('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
    remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
    remove_punc =str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

    lines.translate(remove_digits)
    lines.translate(remove_punc)
    lines.split()

df.apply(clean_pairs)
```

Comment: can we see some sample input v/s expected output as dataframes please. :)

Comment: data frame is a single column containing string given in 'line' variable. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def clean_pairs(lines):
    re_print = re.compile('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
    remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', string.digits)
    remove_punc =str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    lines = lines.translate(remove_digits)
    lines = lines.translate(remove_punc)
    lines = lines.split()
    return lines

df = pd.DataFrame([line])
print(df[0].apply(clean_pairs))
```